# How to get a string before character java

Tags: java

I have an irregular expression that I read from the active directory, example "description: John Newman Logged on: 03.26.2018 9:26:29". quantity of words can be different. I would always like to receive "Logged on" or "Logged off", it all depends on the input data .

I tried it:

```
     String a = Objects.toString(attrs.get("description"));//received values from active directory
     String b = a.split(":")[1];
```

Но это дает мне

```
John Newman Logged on
```

Could you help me? Thanks in advance .

Comment: Please elaborate what exactly do you want? Do you want to fetch the Logged on Details irrespective of the words you receive?

Comment: Exactly. I'm interested two words before the second colon. In this one, this is the connection status

Comment: What have you tried? Please post an [mcve] of your code with a description where it is failing

Comment: Did you try anything before ask question

Comment: String loggedOn = "Logged on"; // always receives "Logged on"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you know what String you are looking for, you can try the following.

```
String s="description: John Newman Logged on: 03.26.2018 9:26:29";
String log1 = null;

if(s.toLowercase().contains("logged on")){
    log1 = "Logged on"; // Your desired string
}else if(s.toLowercase().contains("logged off")){
    log1 = "Logged off"; // Your desired string
}
```

or Simply

```
String log1 = (s.toLowercase().contains("logged on")) ? "Logged on":(s.toLowercase().contains("logged off")) ? "Logged off" : null;
```

Use boundaries if you think that `logged on` can be a part(substring) of User's name as well.

Comment: Your version is more correct. But the connection status can be "logged on" and "logged off", so I would like to know if it  is possible with the extraction of two words before the colon after the status. I hope you understand me.

Comment: @Leo See the edits

Comment: @ Harshita Sethi thanks, my friend, it works!

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you are trying to extract `Logged on: 03.26.2018 9:26:29` info from the main String.

Try this:

```
String s="description: John Newman Logged on: 03.26.2018 9:26:29";
int indx=s.indexOf("Logged on"); 
//will return the index of the substring which is 26 in this case. 
//I hope I didn't count wrong.
String log=s.substring(indx); 
//returns Logged on: 03.26.2018 9:26:29
```

**Edit: To extract only `Logged on`**

> Length of `Logged on`(9) is fixed and so we could use that to extract
>   it.

```
    int endIndx=indx+9; //endIndx becomes 35 and Logged on ends at 34
    //in the below method indx is inclusive and endIndx is exclusive
    //Reason why endIndx points to colon so that we get everything starting from indx to endIndx-1
    String log1=s.substring(indx,endIndx); 
    //returns Logged on
```

Comment: thanks for help , but I'm interested only "Logged On" , without date and time.

Comment: I hope you got the idea. I may have made a counting mistake. Not sure.