# Android Studio - Get specific words from Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I get only the words before ":" from my database as in this image?

[image].

Here is what I have done so far:

```
ListView ListView;
    ArrayList<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseReference mRef;
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
   final ArrayAdapter<String> myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyListActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , myArrayList);
        ListView = findViewById(R.id.Listview);
        ListView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);
      //  Collections.reverse(myArrayList);
        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        mRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ShoppingList").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
        mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) snapshot.getValue();
               // HashMap value = snapshot.getValue(HashMap.class);
                myArrayList.add(""+map);
                myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

[Here is the current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5IRs.png)

How would I modify my code to get only the words before ":"?

ex. the words I want to get are : "bread flour", "all-purpose flour" and so on.

I was able to make it work, I added this:

```
  String ingre = snapshot.child("Ingre").getValue(String.class);
                int index = ingre.indexOf(":");
                if(index != -1){
                    ingre = ingre.substring(0 ,index);
                    myArrayList.add(ingre);
                    myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: So you only want to get, `p`, `v2`, `kq`, `sdf` and so on, right?

Comment: yes, see the image I highlighted the words that I want. "bread flour", "all-purpose flour" and so on

Comment: I updated the image so it is more clear, now it has meaningful words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the `child()` function on the `DataSnapshot` to get to the `Ingre` child, and then use the type-safe `getValue(String.class)` call to get that node's value:

```
public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
    String ingre = snapshot.child("Ingre").getValue(String.class);
    int index = ingre.indexOf(":");
    ingre = ingre.substring(index); 
    myArrayList.add(ingre);
    myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Also see: [How to get a string before character java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49484073/how-to-get-a-string-before-character-java)

Comment: Great, but how can I only get part of it? only the words before ":" ?

Comment: I tried your answer, it prints the words after ":", not the one before it. and also ":" is printed, I only wanted the word before ":" without ":" itself. sure if it worked I will accept your answer

Comment: Thank you, you provided helpful links, it worked for me.